# Highlight Text in Reading Pane

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2013

I am trying to highlight specific text in the reading pane, so when you click on a specific email, the reading pane will show the body of the email and specified text highlighted, in this case the word "Test".

Currently, nothing happens.

If I double click the email to open it in a new window, the preview behind it in the reading pane is now highlighted correctly.
It appears the event is firing on open not preview, then the changes take effect on a window that is no longer on top.

```vb
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable = True
   
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector

    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set msg = insp.CurrentItem

        If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set appWord = hed.Application
            Set rng = appWord.Selection
            rng.Find.HitHighlight ("Test")
        End If
    
    End If

    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set insp = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set hed = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
    EventsDisable = False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `ActiveInspector` - it is unrelated to the items shown by the Explorer.
Try the following

```
set hed = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).GetInspector.WordEditor
```

Keep in mind that if the item is shown in an inspector **and** is selected in the active explorer, the change above will highlight text only in the inspector, preview pane will not be affected. If you want to always work with the preview pane, your might want to look into [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object which explicitly exposes the reading pane:

```
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
set hed = sExplorer.ReadingPane.WordEditor
Set appWord = hed.Application
Set rng = appWord.Selection
rng.Find.HitHighlight ("Test")
```